# Memory leak while trying to hold a reference of Fragment view beyond onDestoryView()

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-navigation, leakcanary

I want to go from **FragmentA (RootFragment)** to **FragmentB** but I do not want to recreate the view of FragmentA once it comes back from FragmentB.

I am using Jetpack Navigation for navigating between Fragments.

To achieve the above goal, I have a fragment Fragment like this:

```
class RootFragment : DaggerFragment() {
    private var viewToRestore: View? = null


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return if (viewToRestore != null) {
            viewToRestore!!
        } else {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_root, parent, false)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        viewToRestore = this.view
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }    
}
```

But the **FragmentA** (RootFragment) is leaking once I reach **Fragment B** with the attribute **viewToRestore**.

[image]

Any solution that can work without leak but achieve the same goal?

Comment: Did you expect anything else but a leak when using `override fun onDestroyView() {
        viewToRestore = this.view` ? :) Any real use case of using something like this in a Fragment? You'll get the view when `onCreateView()` is called next time. A regular inflation will be enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The leak is a false positive. It is totally fine from a Fragment point of view to hold onto the View you create in `onCreateView` and return it later, under the condition that your Fragment is not retained or otherwise kept longer than the Context used to create the view is alive.

Comment: Is this thing similar to achieving fragmentTransaction.add() ?  & Why there is no option in android navigation which acts similar to the  fragmentTransaction.add(), rather it defaults to .replace(), and there is not even any option to do add() ?

Comment: @erluxman - I'd suggest [filing an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409828) with exactly what **problem** you're trying to solve (keeping expensive views around, overlap multiple Fragments, save view state, etc, etc) rather than immediately jump to what you think the solution should be as per [the xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Sorry that I am bugging you for days, My usecase is like this : Frag1 -> Displaying Map  Frag2-> SearchingLocation , After I search from frag2 and pass agruments to frag1 I do not want the map to reload/be reinflated rather, I want the camera to move to the particular location. I am doing this thing with Dialog(Fragments) which helps keep the view of Frag1 from being destroyed but I want to achieve this thing with the help of Android Nav. I still have a question, why do we not have an option to do something similar to FragmentTransaction.add() instead of .replace() as the only behavior?

Comment: Let's keep the conversation here to this particular issue, of which the answer as it is right now does answer your question. File an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is a problem for Jetpack navigation as you cannot add when going to another fragment you can just replace:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, FragmentB.newInstance())
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()

supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, FragmentB.newInstance())
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
```

This is the difference `replace` and `add`.

I searched a lot and I guess that jetPack navigation does not support `add` instead of `replace`, so I recommend not to use navigation when it's important not to recreate the first fragment

Comment: I am using android jetpack navigation, you have any idea we can achieve fragmentManager.add() on that setup?

Comment: Cool...  any reason you know that navigation component might have removed the .add() method?

Comment: unfortunately not, I googled a lot but still no answer.